# Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Controller cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I migrated from **"stimulus": "^2.0.0"** to **"@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.0"** 
I got an error **Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Controller cannot be invoked without 'new'** at new _default (message_list_controller.js:1) 
I'm not sure what's wrong with **message_list_controller.js** I just changed from **import { Controller } from "stimulus"** to **import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        this.scrollToBottom()
    }

    scrollToBottom() {
        this.element.scrollTop = this.element.scrollHeight
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise how can I fix this

Comment: https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/issues/433

Comment: It seems this guy found some solution see if it works for you - https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/issues/433#issuecomment-926365479

Comment: @DeepakMahakale It works, I upgraded '@hotwired/stimulus' version from 3.0.0 to 3.0.0-rc.1 and removed 'loose: true'

Answer (score 6):

this can be solved with adjusting the tsconfig.json to include the following:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```